# Get all matching partition which matches regex in hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have one hive table and it is partitions on multiple columns.
I need to fetch partition list with partial partition name.

Ex: table foo_table is partition on

```
| PARTITIONED BY (                                   |
|   `dt` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition.',         |
|   `h` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition.',          |
|   `b` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition.',          |
|   `sv` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition',          |
|   `p` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition',           |
|   `dc` string COMMENT 'Custom Partition')
```

Now i need to fetch all the partition let say where **dt=somevalue**
Below code works if I give value of all the partition columns.

```
List<String> list = ...
list.add("dt=2021-02-01/h=19/b=30/sv=1/p=03/dc=aa")
List<Partition> partitions = HiveMetaStoreClient.getPartitionsByNames(database, tableName, list)
```

But if i want to fetch partition by only giveing `dt=2021-02-01/h=19`this doesn't work.

```
List<String> list = ...
list.add("dt=2021-02-01/h=19") 
//OR
list.add("dt=2021-02-01/h=19/") 
//OR
list.add("dt=2021-02-01/h=19/*") 
//OR
list.add("dt=2021-02-01/h=19/b=*/sv=*/p=*/dc=*")
List<Partition> partitions = HiveMetaStoreClient.getPartitionsByNames(database, tableName, list)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: try `dt=2021-02-01/h=19/`? with a trailing slash.

Comment: @mck just now tried, didn't worked.

Comment: There are `listPartitionsByFilter()`, `listPartitionsByExpr()` methods but they only support `>, <, >= etc.` style of expressions, so probably of no use to you anyways.

Comment: Im new to hive, but isn't this very common problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [listPartitions](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html#listPartitions(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20short)) method available in HiveMetaStoreClient.

```
public List<Partition> listPartitions(String db_name,
                         String tbl_name,
                         List<String> part_vals,
                         short max_parts)
                           throws NoSuchObjectException,
                                  MetaException,
                                  org.apache.thrift.TException
```

you can query for partitions in sequence of your partitions added in hive table.

Example: Table ProductByTypeHeight partitioned [type String, Height int]

**Drawback: you can query for one type of partition at a time.**

```
List<String> pvals1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
        pvals1.add("fruit");
        List<String> pvals2 = new ArrayList<>();
        pvals2.add("vegetable");
        pvals2.add("450");
        List<List<String>> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add(pvals1);
        vals.add(pvals2);
        for (List<String> pval:vals) {
            List<Partition> pNameList = hiveMetaStoreConnector.listPartitions("productdb", "productbytypeheight", pval);
            pNameList.forEach(partition -> {
                List<String> partitionValues = partition.getValues();
                for (int i = 0; i < partitionValues.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(partitionValues.get(i) + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            });
        }
```

Output:

```
fruit 600 
fruit 450 
fruit 400 
vegetable 450
```